# Norm of a functional on square integrable harmonic functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let H be the Hilbert space of square integrable (real) harmonic functions on the unit disk of the complex plane.
I want to find the norm of the linear functional $$h\mapsto h_x(0)$$
Here is my proof that this functional is **bounded.**

The partial derivative $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(z)$ is also harmonic, therefore by the mean value propery and Green's theorem we have
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(0)=\frac{1}{\pi r^2}\int_{D(0,r)} \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(x,y)dxdy= \frac{1}{\pi r^2} \int_{\partial D(0,r)}hdy  $$
$$= \frac{1}{\pi r^2} \int_0^{2\pi} h(re^{it})r \cos tdt$$
This implies
$$ r^2|\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(0)|\leq \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |h(re^{it})|rdt$$
and integrating from $0$ to $R$ yields
$$\frac{R^3}{3}|\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(0)|\leq \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{D(0,R)}|h(w)|dA(w) $$
By Cauchy Schwarz we have
$$|\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(0)|\leq\frac{3}{\pi R^3} (\pi R^2)^{1/2} \int_{D(0,R)} |h(w)|^2dA(w)=\frac{3}{\sqrt{\pi}R^2}\int_{\mathbb D}|h(w)|^2dA(w)$$

Letting $R\to 1$ gives that the operator norm is $\leq  3/\sqrt{\pi}$. However, this is not the best constant. I tried harmonic functions of the form $ax+by$ which have $L^2$ norm $(a^2+b^2)^{1/2} \sqrt{\pi}/2$. In particular, for $h(z)=x$ we get $\|h\|_2= \sqrt\pi/2$ .

Comment: Duplicate of [Show the derivative at origin is bounded linear functional](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/722912/127096).

Comment: Thank's ! I wouldn't find it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a better handling we can get the best bound:

Using Green's theorem and the mean value property we already proved that 
$$|h_x(0)| \leq \frac{1}{\pi r} \int_{0}^{2\pi } |h(re^{it})| |\cos t|dt$$
If we apply now Cauchy Schwarz we get
$$ |h_x(0)|^2\leq \frac{1}{\pi^2 r^2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |h(re^{it})|^2dt \int_{0}^{{2\pi}} \cos^2t dt = \frac{1}{\pi r^2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |h(re^{it})|^2dt $$
Therefore
$$ r^3 |h_x(0)|^2 \leq\frac{1}{\pi } \int_{0}^{2\pi} |h(re^{it})|^2rdt $$
and integrating from $0$ to $R$ we obtain
$$ \frac{R^4}{4} |h_x(0)|^2 \leq \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{D(0,R)} |h(re^{it})|^2dt \leq \frac{1}{\pi} \|h\|_2^2$$
Finally, letting $R\to 1$ and taking roots
$$ |h_x(0)| \leq  \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\|h\|_2$$
which is the best constant.